# Greedy Best First Search - Loops (Romania example)

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I was reading some literature regarding the Greedy Best First Search I encountered many times the road map of Romania as an example application (see [here](http://csc.lsu.edu/~jianhua/AI-Chap3-con.ppt) on slide 5)
.

It is often stated, that the greedy best-first search algorithm can get stuck in loops. This seems logical to me. However, as an example the loop Iasi -> Neamt -> Iasi ... is given (slide 11). I don't see why, because the used heuristic (straight line distance) yields a larger value for Iasi then for the other neighbor of Neamt.

First I thought this is an error, but I found multiple sources giving this loop as example. What am I getting wrong?

EDIT: The goal in these examples is usually to get to Bucharest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are going. The loop would occur if you were going e.g. to Arad. If you are in Iasi, the Neamt is the node which is (heuristicaly) closest out of Iasi's neighbors. Neamt has only one neighbor (and it is not arad), so you always get back to Iasi.

Comment: Good point. But if the goal was Bucharest, Lasi -> Neamt would not be a loop, am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The best-first comes from the order of nodes we select, this particular algorithm is hungry in the sense it takes localy optimal solution. Based on the distance matrix, when in Iasi, it would go for Vaslui neighbor, which has lower estimate than Neamt neighbor.

Comment: btw, If you do not do this already, I really reccomend the Russel and Norvig book on AI. A lot of courses just copy them shallowly, while the original is really a gem.